# How to set server controls value from thread in C# web application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a long running thread in my web page on a button click event

```
var thread = new Thread(StartTaskMonitoring);
thread.Start();
```

In method 'StartTaskMonitoring' I am running a while loop which depends on boolean variable `_StopMonitoring`

Another button "Stop" which resets the `_StopMonitoring` variable which makes start button event stop.

But the problem is that when I am executing thread, I am unable to update UI – say I want to update a textbox in `StartTaskMonitoring` method. Or it could be a progress bar.

Already tested `Updatpanel1.Update()`. It doesn't help. Also cannot get sessions from the thread.

How do I achieve this? so that ui is updated.

Comment: Are you hoping to periodically push UI updates to the client's browser from that thread? That's not going to work.

Comment: How have you structured your ASP?

Answer (score 0):

In a web application, once the request has been completed by the server (all the data sent to the client) the server cannot change anything without some action from the client.

Code on the server has no mechanism to send additional data to the client which will change the display, the only mechanism is for the client to send a request to the server<sup>1</sup>. The client can sent requests (on a timer or in response to a user action) for data and then process the new information to update the UI (this is "AJAX").

---

<sup>1</sup> In the future Web Sockets will provide an easier approach, but that still requires code on the client to process the messages from the server.

Comment: @ChrisBD That and the tags, otherwise it is would, indeed, be a duplicate: yet another "how to use `BeginInvoke`" question.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with background threads is that they may run even after the HTTP request has ended and rendered the page to the user. So talking about modifying UI in threads doesn't make sense. You may checkout the [following article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a process that takes a very long time then I think that your only way forward here is to have the process run as a non-web application, preferably a service and poll it for information using AJAX calls from your web app.

You'd need to provide some control within the service in order to cope with multiple demands for processing from the same session and also what to do if the session expires before the thread has completed.